# UIImage small+medium+large like apple Mail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimage

Is there any reference tutorial for getting the image size in small or medium environment.

I just want to know the calculation of image sizes in terms of Width and Height, How can we calculate UIImage size in pixels when It is small, medium or large like in apple mail.

It is just like when we attach image in Mail it asks small, medium, large..

Plz don't provide [this](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) as I already gone through this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like when we attach image in Mail it asks small, medium, large.. That option?? I was also looking for that solution.

Comment: @anonymous Yes dear looking for that only

Comment: Hmm. I will bookmark this Question..

Comment: There's nothing special about those names.  Mail on Mac OS 10.7 seems to use small => 320, medium => 640, large => 1280.  It scales images so their longest side is limited to the associated length in pixels.  If you want to offer matching scaling in your app, use those sizes.  However, Mail may well change in future versions.

Comment: I had done same as you told, Thanks for response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally seeing from many solutions I got the following solution and done code according this.

We can get images like following.

```
Small = 320 pixels on longest edge JPEG
Medium = 640 pixels on longest edge JPEG
Large =  1296 pixels on longest edge JPEG
```

Where typeOfImage = 0,1,2 for small, medium and large respectively.

```
-(CGSize)getImageWithRespectiveSize:(UIImage *)pImage withType:(NSInteger)typeOfImg
{
    CGSize pSize;
    if(typeOfImg == 0)
        pSize = [self getCGSizesOfImages:320 andImage:pImage];
    else if(typeOfImg == 1)
        pSize = [self getCGSizesOfImages:640 andImage:pImage];
    else if(typeOfImg == 2)
        pSize = [self getCGSizesOfImages:1296 andImage:pImage];
    else 
        pSize = CGSizeMake(pImage.size.width, pImage.size.height);

    return pSize;
}

-(CGSize)getCGSizesOfImages:(NSInteger)pIntPixels andImage:(UIImage *)pImage
{
    CGSize pSize;
    if(pImage.size.width > pImage.size.height)
    {
        CGFloat tmp = pImage.size.height/pImage.size.width*pIntPixels;
        pSize = CGSizeMake(pIntPixels, tmp);
    }
    else if(pImage.size.width < pImage.size.height)
    {
        CGFloat tmp = pImage.size.width/pImage.size.height*pIntPixels;
        pSize =  CGSizeMake(tmp, pIntPixels);       
    }   
    else
    {
        CGFloat tmp = pImage.size.height/pImage.size.width*pIntPixels;
        pSize =  CGSizeMake(tmp, pIntPixels);       
    }
    return pSize;
}
```

and call to function like this

```
CGSize size = [self getImageWithRespectiveSize:imgOriginal withType:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the imageIO framework, it's very easy to setup a method to resize an image. There are a lot of samples around, here is one of the first hit on google, it also explain the classic way with core graphics. [uiimage scaling](http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/01/uiimage-scaling-imageio/)
[EDIT]
If you are looking about how to get the size in bytes you can take a look at this sample code from Apple [Large Image Downsizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)